# Batch command to have program open a file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a portable java launcher program that I use to run .jar files. Once the program is executed a window titled "Open" is launched where you can navigate to and select the .jar file needed.

I am trying to create a batch file to automate this process for one specific file that I need to open on a regular basis. That file is "Build.jar". It is located at "C:\Users\John\Store\Build.jar".

So far I have the following that calls the java launcher:

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Users\John"
start Java Portable Launcher.exe
```

What is the next line to select the .jar file from the prompt that opens?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does `launcer.exe` take parameters? try `launcer.exe build.jar` and `laucher.exe /?` (some programms may expect something like `laucher.exe --h`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the Java Portable Launcher from PortableApps.com, then you just need to append the full file path to the end:

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Users\John"
start "" "Java Portable Launcher.exe" "C:\Users\John\Store\Build.jar"
```

I added `"` quotes to avoid issues with spaces. The first `""` is to avoid issues with `start`'s "title" option.

[Source](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/install-java-runtime-jre-portable-in-usb-flash-drive/)

Comment: That is indeed the one and this is exactly what I was looking for. Works as intended.

Thanks for your time.